# Binary Sankey Diagram in Tableau - Not All Activities Match The Corresponding Number of KPIs

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, data-science, binary-data, sankey-diagram

How do I link my activities variable to only the corresponding KPIs variable?

Using guidance from a number of sources, but primarily the genius of Jeffery Shafer articulated through the [SuperDataScience video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HwCzlA9hI4), I built a Sankey Diagram for my work. For the most part it works, however, I have been trying to figure out how to adjust my Sankey Diagram model to line up each activity with ONLY the corresponding KPIs, but am having no luck.

The data structure looks like this:

### [image]

You'll note I changed the binary value to "", 2 instead of 0, 1 as it makes visual calculations easier. For the "Viz" variable, I have "Activity" for the raw data set, then I copy/paste/replicate the data to mirror the data (required for the model) but with "KPI" for the mirrored data.

In the following image, you'll see my main issue is that the smallest represented activity still shows as corresponding to all KPIs when in fact it does not. I want activity to line up only with the corresponding KPIs as some activities don't correspond with all, or even any, KPIs.

[image: Correlated Activities w/Key Performance Indicators (Binary Sankey Diagram)]

Finally, here is the model very similar to what the above video link shows:

[image]

Can someone help provide insight into how I can adjust the model to fit activities linking only to corresponding KPIs? I appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to the issue, thanks to a helpful Tableau support member named Anthony. It was in the data structure. The data was not structured to only associate "Activities" with their "KPI" values within Tableau's requirements, but every "Activities" value with every "KPI" value. As a result, to achieve the desired result, the data needs to be restructured to only contain a row for every valid "Activities" and "KPI" combination. See the visual below where data is removed to format properly:

[image]**-------------------------------------->**       [image]

Once the table is restructured, the desired visual result should configure with the model. It works like a charm!

Good luck out there!